# duplicate messages from openfire server while retrieving archived messages - XEP-0136

Tags: openfire

I'm using the below code to get archived messages from openfire server using Strophe.js
and under Server->Archiving->Archive Settings enabled both one-to-one and group-chat archive.

```
connection.archive.listCollections(contactId, rsm, function (collections, responseRsm) {
        for(var j = 0; j < collections.length; j++) {
            collections[j].retrieveMessages(rsmMsg, function (messages, responseRsm) {
                for(var i=0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                    console.log(messages[i]);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

While giving the contactId as roster JId, it returns both the messages from one-to-one and group chat and while giving the contactId as room Jid, it retunrs room messages only but the messages got duplicated.

Does any one know how to fix these issues

Comment: Did u find solution?

Comment: Not able to find any solution, till now.